# Make a shortcut to a program that changes to its directory

Tags: symlink, desktop-shortcuts

Sorry if this seems a daft question but I'm still new to Linux. Is there an equivalent of a Windows Shortcut in Linux (as opposed to a link)

The problem I have is this:

I have an application that sits in `/home/user/appDirectory/application.exe` (its a Windows App running under Wine)

I then have a monitoring script that looks for that application to see if it is running.

e.g.

```
application="/home/user/appDirectory/application.exe"

if pgrep -f "$application" > /dev/null 
then
    is_running=1
else
    is_running=0
fi
```

So far so good. But I need to put a 'shortcut' on the desktop so that anyone can go in and easily stop/start the application.

If I create a `link` (and put that on the desktop) and start it from that then the path becomes `/home/user/desktop/link to appDirectory/application.exe` and the monitoring script can't see it.

Is it possible to create a shortcut, that when opened opens as the original location, so the application then starts from the original location?

Comment: it is GNOME ( I think ) on a Debian Server.

Comment: Have a look at .desktop files.

Comment: Which link you're talking about i.e of link application.exe? or of script you mentioned in question?

Comment: it's the link to the application. If I click on `/home/user/desktop/link to appDirectory/application.exe` I need it start as `/home/user/appDirectory/application.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your request seems to be for GUI only, I'd suggest following [jofel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/15241/jofel)s comment about .desktop files. 
Archlinux has a quite good [short summary](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#File_example) over the interesting keys in .desktop files.
A suggestion would be

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Whatever you want
Type=Application
Path=/home/user
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="<prefix>" wine appDirectory/application.exe
```

The `env WINEPREFIX`part may not be required, but use it if you have multiple prefixes or for good measure.

Place the `<Whatever you want>.desktop` file in your $HOME/Desktop folder and you should be set with a new icon that you can click. 
This file would give you at least `appDirectory/application.exe` to grep for.
`Path` is where the command will be executed.
As such, you can modify the `Path` and `Exec` proportions to get more of the path in `Exec` if you need it for grepping.
So with `Path=/` and the rest in `Exec`, you will get the requested behaviour.

However, the need for grepping like this is not clear to me. If it's only run as one instance at a time, you could create a PID file instead and check for if the PID exists, like presented [here](http://www.xarg.org/2009/10/write-a-pid-file-in-bash/) but modified to your needs.
[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/238412/write-a-pid-file-manually-from-bash-script) might also be of interest if you decide to go for a PID file.

Comment: Cheers, the .desktop file looks exactly like what I was after.